# USB mobile broadband modem unusually slow

Tags: networking, usb-modem

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with TP-Link MA260 USB mobile broadband modem.

So far, modem worked 'out of the box' (plug-in, enter sim card pin number and select 'connect').
The problem is connection speed. Usually the speed is between 5 - 20 kB/s.

What's interesting: When I take the sim card out of the modem and put it into my mobile phone (Nokia E5), connect it via USB cable to computer and use the same procedure to connect, the speed is between 100 - 300 kB/s.

I also tried changing connection type in 'network connections' to 3G(UMTS/HSDPA), but it had no effect...

It seems to me that USB modem won't change from 2G to 3G.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: No, just a lot of logs about detecting new hardware... nothing like warning or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Did some research. The modem is working on frequency that is not supported for 3G in my country.
I bought modem directly from my mobile provider and now it is working like a charm.